# C# Add data to each list element

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a `List<Students>`

and `obj`

```
class Student
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int? Klass {get;set}
}
```

and before i fill the list but only with `id` and `name` list.Add(1,"Joht", null) how to now fill `Class` for each element of list means like list.Add(1,"Joht", 8)

Comment: That code won't even compile, you need a property declaration or semicolon. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: What is obj? why is Class not a property? where is the List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're trying to set the `Class`property of all the students in the list at once. You can do this with the `ForEach`extension method (include `using System.Linq`):

```
class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Class { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void test()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        students.Add(new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Name 1" });
        students.Add(new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Name 2" });

        students.ForEach(x => x.Class = 4);
    }
}
```